# postgres 9.3 moving data directory on ubuntu 14

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, nginx

after using

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /data/psql

/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/initdb -D /database
```

and changed the `data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main'`  to `/data/psql'`

on starting the a rails app the nginx log is showing:

> Error during failsafe response: FATAL:  could not open relation
>   mapping file "global/pg_filenode.map": Permission denied

someone have a hint about how to give the permission to the app?

thank's

Comment: I would start from `sudo chown -R postgres:postgres /data/psql`

Comment: well, most probably postgres daemons will run owned postgres user. Configs in /etc/postgres are ofted owned by root and are meant for service to be consumed. but it does not mean data directory should be owned by root or ubuntu... I don't have much experience running postgres on ubuntu, but I never saw PGDATA owned by other user then postgres. did it help?..

Answer (score 0):

[According to docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/creating-cluster.html):

> It's generally recommendable that the **PostgreSQL user own not just the
>   data directory but its parent directory** as well, so that this should
>   not be a problem.

so changing permission back to postgres would be your solution:

```
sudo chown -R postgres:postgres /data/psql
```